# How do I apply a simple formatted text stamp with Pdfmark and Ghostscript

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, ghostscript

I've been successful with applying notes, freehand drawings (Type Ink), highlights etc. using ghostscript and Pdfmarks. Now I want to do the same with a text stamp (not a bitmap), but don't know how.

Peeping into an uncompressed stamped file (thank you pdftk for the uncompressing and Acrobat Professional for the stamping) I see that my custom text stamp ends up as an XObject that is referred to in an Appearance Stream of a Stamp annotation. Complicated, I thought.

So here's my question:
Can one apply a text stamp, say, the text DRAFT under 45 degrees centered on the page, with a simple Pdfmark file, without having to use appearance streams, XObjects etc? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't supply an appearance stream for an annotation then you are totally dependent on whatever the PDF consumer chooses to draw for it. That could be nothing.

However, the PDF 1.7 reference manual says (page 635) under "Rubber Stamp Annotations" :

```
Name    name          (Optional) The name of an icon to be used in displaying the annotation. Viewer applications should provide predefined icon appearances for at least the following standard names:
Approved     Experimental    NotApproved
AsIs         Expired         NotForPublicRelease
Confidential Final           Sold
Departmental ForComment      TopSecret
Draft        ForPublicRelease

Additional names may be supported as well. Default value: Draft.
Note: The annotation dictionary’s AP entry, if present, takes precedence over the Name entry; see Table 8.15 on page 606 and Section 8.4.4, “Appearance Streams.”
```

So yes, you should be able to successfully use 'Draft' as an annotation wihtout supplyinmg an appearance stream, and you can centre it on the page using the required 'Rect' entry. I'm less certain about getting it rotated 45 degrees though, annotations don't have a Matrix entry so I don't believe you can reliably do this without specifying an appearance stream.

Comment: Ken, I appreciate you looking into my problem. But my question is not answered at all. Allow me to rephrase: Can one apply a text stamp, say, the text WIKILEAKS with formatting (color, font) under 45 degrees centered on the page, with a simple Pdfmark file, without having to use appearance streams, XObjects etc? If so, how?

Comment: No, you can't do that. Anything more complex than the simple stamps documented in the PDF Reference Manual will need an appearance stream.